# jq and array of two things: key and value

Tags: json, jq

I have this script:

```
curl -sX 'GET' \
  'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.)|keys,(.[].value|tostring)'
```

and the source of the JSON is:

```
{
  "rates": {
    "btc": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "unit": "BTC",
      "value": 1,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "eth": {
      "name": "Ether",
      "unit": "ETH",
      "value": 14.327,
      "type": "crypto"
    }, ...
```

I cannot make pairs key (coin id, "btc")-value (value of the coin, "1"), what I need is the id of the coin and its value:

```
btc 1
eth 14.327
```

How can I make these two separate arrays as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* get pairs by using the `to_entries` filter. It will transform the dict into an array of items:

```
$ curl <url> | jq ".rates | to_entries"

[
    {
        "key": "btc",
        "value": {
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "unit": "BTC",
            "value": 1,
            "type": "crypto"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "eth",
        "value: {...}
    },
    },
    { ... }
]
```

Once you have such entries, you can access `.key` and `.value.value` of each item to get the pairs you want:

```
$ curl <url> | jq '.rates | to_entries | .[] | [.key, .value.value]'

["btc", 1]
["eth", 14.376]
[...]
```

The same for transforming them into a string:

```
$ curl <url> | jq -r '.rates | to_entries | .[] | "\(.key) \(.value.value)"'
btc 1
eth 14.368
...
```

Note that the `select(.)` you had before seems completely redundant...

Comment: Thank you! Amazing!